# Prepositions 'in' and 'at'

Tags: prepositions

Will we say-
I was born **at** Tacoma in Washington
or
I was born **in** Tacoma in Washington?

Comment: Both are "in," since they are areas rather than single places. You would probably say you were born "at" Tocoma General Hospital since a building is small enough to be considered a location (though "in" the hospital would also be true).

Comment: I could say I was born 'at' or 'in' a hospital, but only 'in' a house.

Comment: Possibly 'at' a palace, castle, country mansion, etc.

Comment: No, it doesn't because my query is about places in relation to each other. I am aware that 'at' is used for specific/smaller locations and 'in' is used for bigger/enclosed spaces. But what about sentences that put places in relation to each other?
For example,
I am at my house. There are five rooms in my house. 

In this particular sense, will we not say 'at Tacoma in Washington'?

Comment: When I took piano exams as a child, I remember noticing that, in the brief biographies of composers supplied in the books of set pieces, they used _at_ for smaller towns and _in_ for cities - for example "W.A. Mozart, born at Salzburg 1756, died in Vienna 1791".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In modern usage usually we use 'at' for a point, a small place, village or small town, and 'in' for a larger area such as a city, state, region, country, or continent. As Tacoma has a population of around 200,000, I would use 'in'.

[At, on or in a place (Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/at-on-and-in-place)

Comment: Up to around 50 - 100 years ago, people sometimes said 'at Bristol' (my home town, current population. 700,000), but now it's always 'in'.